# MVVM-Light pass data to new ViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

Just fiddling around with some WP8.1 development + MVVM-Light toolkit and am having trouble trying to figure out how to achieve something..

Basically:

- I have a `View` (let's call it `View1`) which has a control (`LongListSelector` in this case) that is databound to a Collection of items (let's call them `DataItem`) (which is populated by a `Service` from a `ViewModel`)

And I want it so:

- When the user taps on a particular item in this control, it passes the item tapped (or a property of this item) to a new `View` (called `View2`), which will either create a new `ViewModel` for `View2` or re-use an existing one (depending on the `Key` of the instances in `SimpleIoC`, determined by some property in the `DataItem` tapped).
- This new `ViewModel` then uses the passed property of the `DataItem` tapped in its' constructor to fetch data from a different `Service`

So how can I achieve this? I am thinking of Creating/Registering the new `ViewModel` on the `SelectionChanged` event of the control, passing it in the `Service` and `Property` like so:

```
    private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataItem item = e.AddedItems[0] as DataItem;

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new ViewModel2(new Model2Service(), item.Name));

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Which works fine for the **first** `DataItem` tapped, but not when a second is tapped. 
**Note**: I couldn't register `ViewModel2` in `ViewModelLocator` as I couldn't get `DataItem` properties passed to the constructor for `ViewModel2`, which is why I'm trying to Register it elsewhere.

Not sure if this is abiding by MVVM architecture, I suppose not as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575052/2714911) states that I shouldn't be handling this in my `View`.

So to recap, I want a user to be able to tap on an item in a `LongListSelector` which will then navigate the user to a new `View` which is bound to a new (or existing) `ViewModel` according to a property of the selected item. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Messenger` in MVVMLight? Try creating the instance of the `ViewModel2` in `ViewModelLocator` with the key being some default value. In the ViewModel's constructor, register to receive a `string` property (assuming `item.Name` is a `string`) like this:

```
MessengerInstance.Register<string>(this,name=>{NameProperty=name;});
```

Then in the `LongListSelector_SelectionChanged`, send the `item.Name` like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<string>(item.Name);
```

And then navigate to the page.

---

**Marked as solution but whole comment thread below reveals more details**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution works, but ideally I'd like to have separate instance of `ViewModel`s for **each** different `DataItem` selected, which would allow me to: show previous loaded data before updating on page navigation. Ideas?

Comment: Ok. In the event handler, instead of passing the `DataItem.name` to the viewmodel's constructor, have you tried using overload of `Register` method with `key` argument (using the `item.name`)? Then in the `Navigate` method, pass the `key` as parameter. In the `OnNavigatedTo` method of `View2`, get the parameter and use the `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(key)` to get the required view model and set the `DataContext` on the view.

Comment: Thanks, I had trouble with **all** instances of `ViewModel2` receiving the message and setting `NameProperty` to the message so I modified the solution: when the user taps the `DataItem`, `NavigationService.Navigate` is called, passing a query string `&name=..` to `View2`, and in `OnNavigatedTo` I retrieve this query string and: 1. `GetInstance(name)` that returns old or new instance with `key=name`, 2. a refresh on the data (which sets `NameProperty` upon success and 3. set `DataContext`! Works like a charm. My only gripe is: is setting `DataContext` like this considered _bad design_ in MVVM?

Comment: It isn't bad design per se. Setting the `DataContext` in the XAML is considered best practice as it allows you to see bindings happen at design time. But there are many instances (like this case) where you need to set it in the code-behind. Only disadvantage is that you can't see bindings happen in design time. But there is a work-around for that by creating a design-time DataContext.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. My design-time DataContext is up and running already :), just needed to figure out a more "architecturally consistent" design for my problem - which you've done! Thanks for your help buddy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **UWP with Template Studio 10 and MVVM Light** and want to either:

- Access the parameter that is passed in the NavigationServicesEx.Navigate method
- Call a method in your ViewModel when a page is navigated to.

This [blog](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/how-to-handle-navigation-events-in-mvvm-using-windows-template-studio/) by Marco Minerva is the only guidance I could find that is up to up to date with UWP, Templates Studio 10 and MVVM Light 5.0 (thanks again Marco!)

***tl;dr*** It works by hooking in to the Frame_Navigating event that it missing from the vanilla NavigationServiceEx class.

Create the INavigable interface described in the blog:

```
public interface INavigable
{
    Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode);
    void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e);
    void OnNavigatedFrom();
}
```

Add a handler for the Frame.Navigating event in the NavigationServicesEx class (with some additional plumbing, see blog) then realise the INavigable interface in your ViewModels.

You will then be able to access the parameter that you passed in your Navigate call:

```
NavigationServiceEx.Navigate(typeof(DestinationPage).FullName, yourParameter);
```

In the OnNavigatedToAsync method that you implement in your ViewModel:

```
public Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode)
{
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        YourThing thing = parameter as YourThing;
        this.UseYourThing(thing);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```